# Frequency Response:Matlab Vs Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

i am trying to implement a Matlab code in Python .but i am facing problems in designing filters

Matlab Code:

```
d=fdesign.lowpass('N,Fc',10,40,1600);

Hd = design(d);

freqz(Hd)
```

[image: frequecy response of low pass filter in Matlab]

Python Code:

```
 N=10
 Fc=40
 Fs=1600
 d=firwin(numtaps=N,cutoff=40,nyq=Fs/2)
 Hd=lfilter( d, 1.0, demod_1)
 w,h=freqz(d)
semilogy(w, np.abs(h), 'b')
grid(True)
ylabel('Amplitude (dB)', color='b')
xlabel('Frequency (rad/sample)')
```

[image: frequecny response in Python]

why the filter in python does not have exact frequency response

Comment: In what way are they different? Why are you plotting them differently?  It's impossible to tell the difference when you've plotted them on different scales. Can you use `freqz` to generate a plot directly as in Matlab?

Comment: It's a little hard to see from the plots that they are difference since your units are different.  (I don't think the y-axis is really dB -- isn't it just the magnitude?)  In any case, can you use the same units so we can see the differences?

Comment: when i use freqz direct in Python it does not give any result .i'am new to python  so all i am doing by just taking help from google and all.....

Answer (score 3):

It is the same. Note that the x axis in Matlab includes "pi", whereas in Python it doesn't. And the y axis in Python is labelled in natural units: 10^-1 corresponds to -20 dB, 10^-2 to -40 etc

Comment: ok then tell me ho to apply the  given filter to a signal  in Matlab we use y = filter(Hd,demod_1_b); what should be used in Python   Hd=lfilter( d, 1.0, demod_1_b)?????

Comment: Sorry, my Matlab version doesn't have `fdesign`, and I've never used Python. In any case, that would be a different question...